# Changing some data inside the src parameter of the image and adding hyperlinks to the image PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

I have some text with images inside it.
For example like this

```
texttext<img src="2011-08-15/4/img/123.JPG" alt="" width="528" height="394.3458646616541" >texttext
```

Now I need some  code that searches for the image, finds it, checks if it has class.
If no then I want to change it's soruce from this

```
2011-08-15/4/img/123.JPG
```

to this

```
2011-08-15/4/mini/123.JPG
```

And then add hyperlink to image plus remove width and height params from img tag, so the final result must be like this

```
texttext<a href="2011-08-15/4/img/123.JPG" class="colorbox cboxElement" style="margin: 0 5px 5px 0"><img src="2011-08-15/4/mini/123.JPG" alt=""></a>texttext
```

Here is the code that searches and all I need is code that does all the manipulations.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    if(!$img->getAttribute('class')){
        // ......Here must be some code that does all the work......
        $article_header = $doc->saveXml();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ? If you can't write the whole code maybe you could help me with small examples ?

1. How to change something inside src parameter and save .
2. How to remove width and height parameters from img tag .
3. How to add hyperlink tag to im tag.

I need this 3 techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    if(!$img->getAttribute('class')){
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
        $newSRC = str_replace('/img/', '/mini/', $src);
        $img->setAttribute('src', $newSRC);

        $img->setAttribute('width', '500'); // set new attribute value
        $img->setAttribute('height', '500'); // set new attribute value

        $img->setAttribute('title', 'New title'); // set new attribute and value

        $img->removeAttribute('width'); // remove attribute
        $img->removeAttribute('height'); // remove attribute

        $href = $doc->createElement('a', '');
        $addhref = $img->parentNode->insertBefore($href, $img);
        $href->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com');

        $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
        $href->appendChild($img);

    }
}

echo $doc->saveXml();
```

1. loop images
2. get the ones without class
3. change src, width, height whatever you want, remove attributes ...
4. add `a` Element before `img` Element
5. add `href` attribute and whatever you want
6. remove `img` Element with no class
7. append `img` to `a` Element

Comment: Thanks a lot, started to implement this techniques into my project. What about removing width and height param from img tag ? You have setAttribute think which changes atributes value, but what about removing attribute ?

Comment: @David read the post ... ``$img->removeAttribute('width');`` .. i set that code inside :)

Comment: Oh sorry . My bad. Thanks againg. I think that's complete answer to my questions. Thanks!